# Retrieving Text between <span>Text</span> in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, html

I am facing problem in retrieving Subject title of a mail from Unread mails using Selenium webdriver-C#.

Here's the HTML code :

```
<div class="ae4 UI UJ" gh="tl">
 <div class="Cp">
  <div>
    <table id=":8e" class="F cf zt" cellpadding="0">
    <colgroup>
    <tbody>
      <tr id=":8d" class="zA zE">
       <td class="PF xY"></td>
       <td id=":8c" class="oZ-x3 xY" style="">
       <td class="apU xY">
       <td class="WA xY">
       <td class="yX xY ">
       <td id=":87" class="xY " role="link" tabindex="0">
        <div class="xS">
         <div class="xT">
          <div id=":86" class="yi">
          <div class="y6">
          **<span id=":85">
             <b>hi</b>
            </span>**
            <span class="y2">
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </td>
       <td class="yf xY "> </td>
       <td class="xW xY ">
     </tr>
```

I am able to print 'emailSenderName' in console but unable to print 'text' (subject line i.e. "hi" in this case) as it is between span tags. Here's my code.

```
 //Try to Retrieve mail Senders name and Subject
        IWebElement tbl_UM = d1.FindElement(By.ClassName("Cp")).FindElement(By.ClassName("F"));
        IList<IWebElement> tr_ListUM = tbl_UM.FindElements(By.ClassName("zE"));
        Console.WriteLine("NUMBER OF ROWS IN THIS TABLE = " + tr_ListUM.Count());
        foreach (IWebElement trElement in tr_ListUM)
        {
            IList<IWebElement> td_ListUM = trElement.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));
            Console.WriteLine("NUMBER OF COLUMNS=" + td_ListUM.Count());
            string emailSenderName = td_ListUM[4].FindElement(By.ClassName("yW")).FindElement(By.ClassName("zF")).GetAttribute("name");
            Console.WriteLine(emailSenderName);
            string text = td_ListUM[5].FindElement(By.ClassName("y6")).FindElement(By.TagName("span")).FindElement(By.TagName("b")).Text;
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
```

I had also tried by directly selecting the Text from  tag of 5th Column (td), which contains the subject text (in my case), but no results.

I might went wrong somewhere or may be there is some other way of doing it.

Please suggest, Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
findElement(By.cssSelector("div.y6>span>b")).getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not working too.
Also, getText() method is not present :(

Comment: I try to run in debug mode. But, text property field returns Nothing (" ").

Comment: I tried with same html code with java it is giveing hi as output.
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.y6>span>b")).getText());

Comment: This answer simply doesn't work in the C# world, as per the original question.

Comment: @Holf : I don't know C# selenium bindings. I just posted this answer to give some idea regarding locator & method that might be available with different name in C#.

Answer (score 5):

The 'getText' method available in the Java implementation of Selenium Web Driver seems to do a better job than the equivalent 'Text' property available in C#.

I found a way of achieving the same end which, although somewhat convoluted, works well:

```
public static string GetInnerHtml(this IWebElement element)
{
    var remoteWebDriver = (RemoteWebElement)element;
    var javaScriptExecutor = (IJavaScriptExecutor) remoteWebDriver.WrappedDriver;
    var innerHtml = javaScriptExecutor.ExecuteScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element).ToString();

    return innerHtml;
}
```

It works by passing an IWebElement as a parameter to some JavaScript executing in the Browser, which treats it just like a normal DOM element. You can then access properties on it such as 'innerHTML'.

I've only tested this in Google Chrome but I see no reason why this shouldn't work in other browsers.

Comment: This was very effective for me. This post provides a little more discussion as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16687715/text-property-on-selenium-web-element-is-empty-even-though-i-can-inspect-it-with. In my case, the element wasn't visible, so Text always returned an empty string. @Holf's code snippet works for hidden elements as well.

Comment: Does this work when using the local chrome driver instead of the remote driver?  Typically I have to pass in the current driver.

Comment: Extremely clever, thanx!

Answer (score 4):

Using `GetAttribute("textContent")` instead of `Text()` did the trick for me.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul.list span")).GetAttribute("textContent")
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Worked on PhantomJS. The solution is to get the value using GetAttribute("textContent"):

```
Driver.FindElementsByXPath("SomexPath").GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably too late but could be helpful for someone.

```
        IWebElement spanText= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'TEXT TO LOOK FOR')]"));
        spanText.Click();


        IWebElement spanParent= driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[contains(text(), 'TEXT TO LOOK FOR')]/ancestor::li"));
        spanParent.FindElement(By.XPath(".//a[contains(text(), 'SIBLING LINK TEXT')]")).Click();
```

bonus content here to look for siblings of this text
once the span element is found, look for siblings by starting from parent. I am looking for an anchor link here. The dot at the start of XPath means you start looking from the element spanParent

```
<li>
<span> TEXT TO LOOK FOR </span>
<a>SIBLING LINK TEXT</a>
</li>
```

Comment: Legend! Cheers, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Visual Studio 2017 Unit test project. I'm trying to find the search result from a typeahead control.

```
    IWebElement searchBox = this.WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("searchEntry"));
searchBox.SendKeys(searchPhrase);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);

IList<IWebElement> results = this.WebDriver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".tt-suggestion.tt-selectable"));
if (results.Count > 1)
{

    searchResult = results[1].FindElement(By.TagName("span")).GetAttribute("textContent");
}
```