# Text property on selenium web element is empty even though I can inspect it with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, selenium

Without posting pages of C# code and markup, has anyone got a reason why this code

```
 var link = _driver.FindElement(By.Id(field + "Field"));
 var id = link.GetAttribute("id");
 var text = link.Text;
```

given this markup

```
<a id="ForenameField" href="/MyUrl/MyFolder/MyId">3 errors</a>
```

Assigns an empty string to the text variable, but if I put a breakpoint on the second or third line and inspect the link variable, I can see the inner text of the element against the Text property on the inspector, it reads "3 errors", but the value of text is an empty string. It is not hidden, I can see the text if I add a watch or use quickview, any ideas?

Comment: What kind of element is it? As in, we can't help without some markup to back this to.

Comment: @Arran, there you go, hope you can help.

Comment: what programming language is that? I would use `getText()` method in java...

Comment: Sorry it is in C#, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, it's my bad. Using jquery to toggle class on the div that contains the html in the question, meant that although users see the div appearing, the class that hides the div is still in the tag. A bit like this

```
<div class="hideThis showThis"><!-- my elements /--></div>
```

This makes it so that Selenium is right not give me a text value. It is strange however that the Visual studio debugger thinks that there should be a value. Visual Studio seems to go with what I can see, but Selenium is more pedantic about the *hideThis* class being there.

I go with the idea that if you can't see it you can't interact with it, so it is worth looking up the html graph from the element you expect to have a value to see if any class is present which would hide your element.

Feel free to recommend that I delete this rather obvious wisdom.

Comment: In other words, 
    Text {get { if(Displayed) return js.dom.InnerText(); else return string.Empty;}}

Comment: For hidden elements to retrieve it's text you just can use `GetAttribute("innerHTML")`.

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted over a year ago, but I had this exact problem too and came across this thread. I was able to solve it by just waiting for the DOM to load--some elements aren't visible until the DOM is updated. So just putting Thread.Sleep(6000) or whatever after navigating to the page got it to work for me.

Comment: Hey Sarah, Just noticed this post. I think at the time, I had some pop up css stuff going on, that made me think about looking at the styles. Rather than doing a thread sleep, you could use Coypu which is a wrapper around selenium, to let you retry for a duration rather than wait  for an element to appear (saves time). Thanks for posting! p.s. you might find www.naughtystepbdd.org useful if you like what Coypu does.