# How do I get around this layer of javascript using C# selenium?

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

The following is the source code that I am attempting to work with. I have attempted to use methods such as:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//span[@data-bind = 'text: Caption']")).Click();
driver.FindElement((By.XPath("//*[contains(text(),'document')]"))).Click();
```

All the conventional selenium methods that I have been using in my project have not been able to find anything.

```html
<div class="caption" data-bind="css: { 'doc-downloader-wrapper': $data.IsDocument() }">
  <a data-bind="css: { 'protected': IsProtectedDocument(), 'doc-downloader': $data.IsDocument(), 'no-       details': !$data.HasDetails() }, attr: { href: Link, target: $data.IsLinkDocument() ? '_blank' :         '_self' }">
    <span data-bind="text: Caption"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieving Text between <span>Text</span> in Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14057699/retrieving-text-between-spantext-span-in-selenium-c-sharp)

Comment: Have you tired using `Actions`?

Comment: I'm not acquainted with Selenium C# so this may be a stupid suggestion. Can you select with a CSS selector? e.g. `document.querySelector('span[data-bind="text: Caption"]')`

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an dynamic element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *ElementToBeClickable* and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) as solutions:

- `CssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.CssSelector("div.caption[data-bind*='doc-downloader-wrapper']>a[data-bind*='IsProtectedDocument']>span[data-bind$='Caption']"))).Click();
  ```
- `XPath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//div[@class='caption' and contains(@data-bind, 'doc-downloader-wrapper')]/a[contains(@data-bind, 'IsProtectedDocument')]/span[contains(@data-bind, 'Caption')]"))).Click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try.